# Converting a multi dimensional string array into doubles

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, syntax-error

I have been trying to parse a CSV file forever and I am almost there. I have gotten it to a multi-dimensional array of strings using this code:

```
let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "BaseballSimStats", withExtension: "csv")
    var file = String()
    do {
        file = try String(contentsOf: path!)
        print(file)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    let stringarray = file.components(separatedBy: "\n").map{ $0.components(separatedBy: ",") }
```

Now the last step is to turn it into a Double. I am using this code:

```
probs = Double[[stringarray]]
```

I get an error saying that the type has no subscript errors. I get rid of the subscript references and the error goes away. Why is this error here and how can I get rid of it? Thanks!

Comment: can you please explain what does your array contain.. and what do you expect your probs variable to be?

Comment: the array contains 30 rows of 6 strings that are numbers like this: 15.14376997. Probs should be the same exact thing as the previous array but with type Double

Answer (score 0):

I used `.map()` to map the String  into a Double, this should work for nested array

```
var strArray = [["1.00000","1.10000"],["2.00000","2.10000"]]
var doubleArray = strArray.map { (arr: Array) -> Array<Any> in
    return arr.map({ (value: String) -> Double in
        return Double(value)!
    })
}
print(strArray)
print(doubleArray)
```

I am not sure if the double map was needed.

I am not a swift guru but this code should help you achieve what you want..

Comment: No need to force-unwrap if you use flatMap

Comment: I ran it in playground and it worked. Then I put it in my code and it is telling me Array<Any> isn't compatible with Double.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `Double[[stringarray]]` syntax so I don't know how that's supposed to work.  I do know [you can't just cast between array types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25470683).

The simplest way is probably to wrap the innermost call with `Double.init()`:

```
file.components(separatedBy: "\n").map{ $0.components(separatedBy: ",").map { Double($0)! }}
```

Of course, there's a bit more to CSV than just splitting on commas and assuming everything is a valid number, so I'd highly recommend using an existing CSV parsing library for any real data.

Comment: I tried using a csv parser via cocoa pods but could not get it too work. When I run this code I get an error say that it found nil.

Comment: I set `let file = "1,2,3\n4,5,6"` and ran this, and it worked fine for me.  If you have values which can't be parsed as Doubles, you'll need to define what you want it to do with them, and implement that.  The language won't allow them to be put in a `[[Double]]`.

Comment: Makes sense. The number I states above is a double right?